# Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS. - error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got problem with second question, becasue i receive error "*Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.*". Can you help me?

```
Select P.Name, P.ProductCategoryID, PC.Name, Max(P.ListPrice) as MaxPrice
from SalesLT.Product as P
join SalesLT.ProductCategory as PC
on PC.ProductCategoryID=P.ProductCategoryID
where P.ListPrice=
    (select Max(ListPrice)
    from SalesLT.Product as P2
    where P2.ProductCategoryID=P.ProductCategoryID)
group by P.Name, P.ProductCategoryID, PC.Name
order by MaxPrice desc;

go

with sale_cte as 
    (Select PC.Name, P.ProductCategoryID, P.Listprice,
    ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by PC.Name order by P.Listprice) as RN
    from SalesLT.Product as P
    join SalesLT.ProductCategory as PC
    on PC.ProductCategoryID=P.ProductCategoryID)
Select PC.Name,
    (select *
    from sale_cte)
from SalesLT.ProductCategory as PC
wher RN=1
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the error is in below part

```
Select PC.Name,
    (select *
    from sale_cte)
from SalesLT.ProductCategory as PC
where RN=1
```

This can be re-written as

```
select * from sale_cte
wher RN=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to list PC.Name separately, as it is part of the whole list of columns (*)

Comment: But I want to see a product category name (have the same result as in the first quary) in the second one.